# PHP Get File Content

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to display the content of one website on another.  This is what I currently have:

```
<?php 
  $file = file_get_contents ('http://linkto.com/the-page'); 
  echo $file; 
?>
```

It gets everything from that page. However, I only need to get one table from it. I basically just need all the content from `<table id=arc>` to `</table>`.

Is there any simple way to edit my code to just get that table?

Comment: Start reading about [SimpleXML](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [`DOMDocument`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Neither is difficult to use.

Comment: and of course you have permission to use this other sites page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using PHP's native DOM parser, [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile( 'http://linkto.com/the-page');

// Get the desired table 
$table = $doc->getElementById( 'arc');

// Print the table's HTML
echo $doc->saveHTML( $table);
```

Comment: I agree that this is what the OP wants, but would like to note that it still loads all of the content, it just provides a way of **accessing* what is wanted.  Probably irrelevant, but...

Comment: @jmoreno - I would be very interested in a solution that does not load all of the content from a remote site. `:)`

Comment: @nickb If it's HTTP (which I'm assuming it is), then the [HTTP Range header](http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/) would work given the resource has `Accept-ranges: bytes`. Not that this is a great idea, because there is no what to know in which range the `#arc` element would be.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder While that may be possible, you make two assumptions (that the resource has a specific header, and that you could determine what range of bytes the element in question is) that make an implementation impractical, which is why I would be interested in a *solution* that doesn't load all of the content, not just a *theory*. If theories were acceptable, I would color all of the bits that comprise the `#arc` table hot pink so they would be easy to see as they came off the wire `;)`